How to use vertex attributes as labels in GeoGraphPlot?
I would like to plot a map using GeoGraphPlot with some cities, using "Name" attribute for labels. The code for this is
Szekesfehervar = SemanticInterpretation["Székesfehérvár"];
Nis = SemanticInterpretation["Niš"];
Ioannina = SemanticInterpretation["Ioannina"];
Alexandroupoli = SemanticInterpretation["Alexandroupoli"];

GeoGraphPlot[{
  Szekesfehervar \[UndirectedEdge] Nis, 
  Nis \[UndirectedEdge] Ioannina, 
  Ioannina \[UndirectedEdge] Alexandroupoli},
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Below]
]

Unfortunately, for some locations, the labels (obtained using "Name") are not exactly what I want. For example, for Niš, Serbia, the label is City of Nis, Nišava, Serbia.

How can I alter the selected labels? Would it be possible to process "Name" to get, for example, only some part of it?

How about specifying a rule for VertexLabels?
GeoGraphPlot[
 {Szekesfehervar \[UndirectedEdge] Nis, 
  Nis \[UndirectedEdge] Ioannina, 
  Ioannina \[UndirectedEdge] Alexandroupoli}, 
 VertexLabels -> {Entity["AdministrativeDivision" | "City", List[a_, __, b_]] :> 
   Placed[Style[a<>", "<>b, Medium, Background->White], Below]}]



Look at the documentation for GeoGraphPlot: Scope > Labeling to see how you can specify custom vertex labels.

But let me instead fix your actual underlying problem.
Don't use SemanticInterpretation if you know exactly what you are looking for. It returned an "AdministrativeDivision" entity for Niš (and Székesfehérvár) instead of "City":
Nis // InputForm
(* Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Nis", "Nisvava", "Serbia"}] *)

Nis["Name"]
(* "City of Nis, Nišava, Serbia" *)

You could instead use Interpreter, but it looks like it cannot find Niš:
Interpreter["City"]["Niš"]
(* Failure[...] *)
Interpreter["City"]["Niš, Serbia"]
(* Failure[...] *)

To get to the correct city entity, you have to dig around a little bit:
SemanticInterpretation["Cities in Niš"]
(* {Entity["City", {"BrziBrod", "CentralSerbia", "Serbia"}], 
    Entity["City", {"DevetiMaj", "CentralSerbia", "Serbia"}], 
    Entity["City", {"DonjaVrezina", "CentralSerbia", "Serbia"}], 
    Entity["City", {"DonjiKomren", "CentralSerbia", "Serbia"}], 
    Entity["City", {"Nis", "CentralSerbia", "Serbia"}], 
    Entity["City", {"NiskaBanja", "CentralSerbia", "Serbia"}]} *)

So here you have it:
Nis = Entity["City", {"Nis", "CentralSerbia", "Serbia"}];

And the same goes for Székesfehérvár:
Szekesfehervar = Entity["City", {"Szekesfehervar", "Fejer", "Hungary"}];

GeoGraphPlot[{Szekesfehervar \[UndirectedEdge] Nis, 
  Nis \[UndirectedEdge] Ioannina, 
  Ioannina \[UndirectedEdge] Alexandroupoli}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Below], PlotRangePadding -> 1]



Thanks, this solves the problems I had when using Entity["City", {"Niš", "Serbia"}].
